# How to use $-1$ in some form instead of $e^i$ to represent a $1$ radian rotation

Tags: complex-numbers, rotations

The first fact:
A complex number whose modulo equals 1 lies on the unit circle, and finding the square root is equivalent to halving its angle on the unit circle. The angle of -1 is 180 degrees, the square root of -1 means that the angle of $i$ is 90 degrees, the angle of the square root of $i$ is 45 degrees, and the angle of the square root of $i$ is 22.5 degrees ... which is described as the following picture

[image]

The second fact

$(1+i/n)^n=e^i   \ when \ n \to \infty $ which means a rotation of one radian,

To a summary, $i$ multiplying a real number means a $\pi/2$ rotation,  $i$ at the power of $e$ means a 1 radian rotation.

I have a strange idea, could use -1 of the form in the fist fact to represent 1 radian rotation.

i.e. how to use $\sqrt{-1}  \ \sqrt{\sqrt{-1}} \ \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{-1}}} \ ...$ to represent an arbitray radian rotation by combination or some what you could think

Comment: It is not clear what your idea is or what you are asking for. Please clarify.

Comment: Maybe write $(-1)^{1/2}, (-1)^{1/4}, \dots (-1)^{1/2^k},\dots$ (looks mmore professional).   Choose some of them (based on binary expansion of $a$) to get $(-1)^a$, defined as $(-1)^a = e^{i\pi a}$.  In particular, to get $e^i$ use the binary expansion of $1/\pi$.

Comment: A better view, I aim to understand it from different and vivid view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $\pi$-radian rotation from $1$ gives $-1$; that is, $$-1=e^{\pi i}$$  Taking $\pi$-th roots, $$(-1)^{\frac{1}{\pi}}=e^i$$

(If you liked this, give GEdgar's comment an upvote.)